# This message cannot be recycled because it is still in use

Tags: android, android-handler

I'm trying to use [this article](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/18/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-ii) to create asynchronous UDP socket.

So I've this code:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Message;

import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class UdpThread
    extends HandlerThread {

    private static final String TAG = "UDP";
    private final Handler uiHandler, workerHandler;
    private final DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

    public UdpThread(final Handler uiHandler, final String hostname, final int port) throws SocketException {
        super(TAG);
        this.uiHandler = uiHandler;
        start();
        workerHandler = new Handler(getLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(final Message msg) {
                /*
                if (msg.what == port && msg.obj == hostname) {
                    final InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to " + address);
                    try {
                        socket.connect(address);
                    } catch (SocketException se) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(se);
                    }
                }
                */
                msg.recycle(); //java.lang.IllegalStateException: This message cannot be recycled because it is still in use.
                return true;
            }
        });
        workerHandler.obtainMessage(port, hostname).sendToTarget();
    }
}
```

But when I run the code, I get the mentioned `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This message cannot be recycled because it is still in use.` when trying to recycle the message. Why is that and how to solve it and prevent memory leaks?

Comment: I don't think you have to use recycle

Comment: This seems correct. even when I start spamming the messages, the memory consumption seems flat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well first of all lets see how `Message` `recycle()` method works.

```
public void recycle() {
    if (isInUse()) {
        if (gCheckRecycle) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This message cannot be recycled because it "
                    + "is still in use.");
        }
        return;
    }
    recycleUnchecked();
}
```

So you are getting `IllegalStateException` if it is in use

`isInUse()` just checks flag and looks like:

```
boolean isInUse() {
        return ((flags & FLAG_IN_USE) == FLAG_IN_USE);
    }
```

And when we try to read about that flag we see description:

> If set message is in use.
>
> This flag is set when the message is enqueued and remains set while it
>   is delivered and afterwards when it is recycled.  The flag is only
>   cleared when a new message is created or obtained since that is the
>   only time that applications are allowed to modify the contents of the
>   message.
>
> It is an error to attempt to enqueue or recycle a message that is
>   already in use.

**So what we have**

1. You cant recycle message until its "in use"
2. It is "in use" until new message obtained or created

**How to solve the problem**

There is method `recycleUnchecked()` inside Message class to recycle message object **even** if it is in use.Thats what you need! Description of it:

> Recycles a Message that may be in-use.
>
> Used internally by the MessageQueue and Looper when disposing of
>   queued Messages.

Worst thing that it uses internally and has package access. Good thing that it uses internally when you call:

```
handler.removeMessages(int what)
```

**So I guess final solution is:**

replace

```
msg.recycle();
```

to

```
try {
     msg.recycle(); //it can work in some situations
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     workerHandler.removeMessages(msg.what); //if recycle doesnt work we do it manually
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't call `msg.recycle()` yourself, message is recycled automatically by Looper after it has been dispatched/processed (after your `handleMessage()` returns), see [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#154).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AsyncTask` to delete the message when the handler thread finish to proceed it.

```
//[..]
        //synchronized with the handler thread
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            new MessageDestructor().execute(msg);
            return true;
        }
//[..]
private class MessageDestructor extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> {
    Message msg;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Message... params) {
        msg = (Message) params[0]; 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       msg.recycle(); //synchronized with the main thread
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```